# Drawing value history using Google Charts and SteppedAreaChart

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am drawing value history from the database. Basically every time the value changes, trigger saves the old value, new value as well as date and time of said change.

In a web app, I need to visualize said changes.
Since the values do not gradually change, I decided to use stepped area chart.

sample input:

```
DateTime         | Value
2017-03-14 22:50 | 14
2017-03-14 22:55 | 16
2017-03-14 23:00 | 10
```

The problem is that Google Charts draw it like the value is 14 until 22:50, 16 until 22:55 and 10 until 23:00. I obviously need the opposite. Instead of rendering the value UNTIL the interval, I need the line to START at said DateTime and continue until the value changes.

Right now I'm using line chart to render it, because it does exatly what I need. Well as far as plotting the points where they belong. The connecting line just doesn't make sense but it's as close as I can get.

Is there a non-hack way of doing so? I basically need to change rendering mode

```
line chart:
/''\__/\_
01  0  10
current stepped area chart behavior:
███▄▄▄█▄▄
01  0  10
desired shape:
▄███▄▄▄█▄
01  0  10
(spaces mean there was no change in value at that time)
```

Any non-hack way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there aren't any standard options you can set to get the desired chart

it all boils down to the data fed to the chart

you'll need to insert a new row for each *change*

the new row will need the next x value and the previous y value

sample input:

```
DateTime         | Value
2017-03-14 22:50 | 14
2017-03-14 22:55 | 14
2017-03-14 22:55 | 16
2017-03-14 23:00 | 16
2017-03-14 23:00 | 10
2017-03-14 23:05 | 10
```

the last "new row" is optional, but helps with the visualization

you could union a couple sql statements to pull from the database,

but using two google data tables would probably be easier

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  var newData = data.clone();

  data.addRow([new Date('2017-03-14 22:50'), 14]);
  data.addRow([new Date('2017-03-14 22:55'), 16]);
  data.addRow([new Date('2017-03-14 23:00'), 10]);

  hTicks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      newData.addRow([
        data.getValue(i, 0),
        data.getValue(i - 1, 1)
      ]);
    }
    newData.addRow([
      data.getValue(i, 0),
      data.getValue(i, 1)
    ]);
    hTicks.push(data.getValue(i, 0));
  }
  newData.addRow([
    new Date(data.getValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 0).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 5)),
    data.getValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 1)
  ]);

  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();

  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(newData, {
      chartArea: {
        bottom: 60
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
        ticks: hTicks
      },
      vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0
        }
      },
      height: 400
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Definitely helped. changed from
SELECT [id], CONVERT(varchar(16),[datetime],120) [datetime], [value], [warning], [danger] FROM (
to
SELECT [id], CONVERT(varchar(16),[datetime],120) [datetime], [value], [old_value], [warning], [danger] FROM (
and added one extra line
data.addRows([
  [new Date(datapoint.datetime),datapoint.old_value, datapoint.warning, datapoint.danger],
  [new Date(datapoint.datetime),datapoint.value, datapoint.warning, datapoint.danger],
]);
and this is the result: http://imgur.com/a/aszAh
So simple change, yet so much difference. Thanks man! Appreciate it! :)